# ITRS geneos window service

Tags: monitoring, geneos

Could you please let me know how can we start a window service using geneos if it is stopped or staled

Thanks in advance

BR
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with Windows Win Services Plug-in.

Comment: could any one confirm?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WIN-SERVICES plug-in to display services, it comes with start/stop functionalities. All you need to do is to do a right click on the status of the service you want to start/stop and it will give you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Win-Services plugin. From the active console, right click on the particular service and select start/stop service.